# revoke create on public schema is not working, Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL 12.14, and I am `superuser`.  I don't want user1 to create tables in public schema.  I have already set readonly permission, also grant usage privilege, and revoke create permission on public from user1. For some reasons, user1 still is able to create tables. Is there a way to fix it - forbid readonly users `CREATE` tables in public schema, while `superuser` are allowed.

After connecting to the database, it directs to public by default. This is what I ran (no error message pop up after I ran this):

```
CREATE USER user1 WITH PASSWORD 'this-is-password';
GRANT readonly TO user1;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO user1;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO user1;
REVOKE CREATE ON SCHEMA public FROM user1;
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only revoke privileges that have been granted. The attempt to revoke `CREATE` from `user1` does nothing, because that privilege had never been granted to that user.

Review the privileges on the schema:

```
SELECT p.privilege_type,
       CASE WHEN p.grantee = 0
            THEN 'PUBLIC'
            ELSE p.grantee::regrole::text
       END AS grantee
FROM pg_namespace AS n
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL aclexplode(n.nspacl) AS p
WHERE n.nspname = 'public';
```

You will probably see that `CREATE` was granted to `PUBLIC`. So you can only revoke that privilege:

```
REVOKE CREATE ON SCHEMA public FROM PUBLIC;
```

Comment: Do superuser still have CREATE privilege after I REVOKE FROM PUBLIC?

Comment: Superusers are exempt from privilege checks. But you don't need a superuser: you can grant the privilege to individual users.